# Global method for cart in laravel?

Tags: laravel-4

I created my own cart in Laravel. I want to be able to basically gain access to it globally, by using the same convention as laravel. Something like:

```
Cart::contents()
```

How would you set this up the most correct way in Laravel?

Comment: Setup your Cart class as a Facade. http://laravel.com/docs/facades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a permenant cart you should store it in database

example:

```
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

        $cart = $user->cart;

        $user->cart = $user->cart . $product . ',';

        $user->save();
```

save $products in cart column(varchar)

but if you want a temporary cart you should it in session

example:

```
       Session::put('cart', Session::get('cart') . $product . ',');
```

and when you want to call your cart

example:

```
     $cart = explode(',', $user->cart);
```

or

```
     $cart = explode(',', Session::get('cart'));
```

The steps to save:
1 - implode cart like 'mobile,pc,tablet'
2 - save it to database or session
The steps to call:
1 - Call cart from database or session
2 - explode cart like array([0]=>'mobile', [1]=>'pc', [2]=>'tablet')